# Perl HTML Cleaning

Tags: html, perl

How can i make the HTML::Clean Module work in this perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

require LWP::UserAgent;

open FH, "<", "text.txt";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);

foreach my $line (<FH>) {
    my $response = $ua->get($line);
    my $h = new HTML::Clean(\$response);

    if ($response->is_success) {
        print $response->decoded_content;
    }
    else {
        die $response->status_line;
    }
}
close FH;
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you expect HTML::Clean to do for you? You appear to be doing nothing with the object that you have created.

Answer (score 3):

The [HTML::Clean](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aClean) constructor method takes an argument which is either a filename or a reference to a string containing HTML. You seem to be passing it an [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aResponse) object. Try passing it the HTML instead.

```
my $response = $ua->get($line);
my $html = $response->decoded_content;
my $h = HTML::Clean->new(\$html);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. I also put the -use HTML::Clean;- in the beginning. But no luck.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work". What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? What are you hoping to do? What doesn't happen that you would like to happen? What does happen that you don't want to happen? Be explicit. Best to answer this by editing the original question.